# Convergent sequence and index (N)

Tags: real-analysis, convergence-divergence

Okay so this problem looks simple, but I can't seem to get my notation right or something. The math tutor won't show me where i made the mistake and just goes on saying "that's not how you learn math". Jesus... anyways.

*Prove that the sequence of points {$p_1, p , p_2, p, p_3, p,...$} is convergent if and only if [$\lim_{n\to infinity} $$p_n$ = $p$]

Proof)

Let {$q_n$} represent the sequence of points {$p_1, p, p_2, p, p_3, p,...$}. For any $\epsilon$ > 0. There is an index N such that d($p$, $q_n$)<$\epsilon$ for any $n>N$.

Now lets denote {$q_{2n}$} = {$p$} since every value in this subsequence of {$q_{2n}$} converges to $p$.

Now lets denote another subsequence {$q_{2n+1}$} = {$p_n$}. Since we are given that the [$\lim_{n\to infinity} $$p_n$ = $p$] we know that this second subsequence also converges to $p$.

Since both subsets {$q_{2n}$} & {$q_{2n+1}$} complete {q_n}, we know that {q_n} converges to $p$. PROOF IS COMPLETE.

- Okay so is this proof good or what?? Like omfg,what is up with my math tutor? whatevs, can you give me any insights as to what is up??

*Some problems I see is that I do not specify a specific index N. However, I feel as though my explanation is convincing enough. If you were to specify a specific N can you explain that to me?

Comment: It does only show $\Longleftarrow$

Comment: i'm sorry but what does that mean?

Comment: You have shown that if lim p_n = p then {p_1, p, p_2, p, ...} is convergent. YOu also have to show that if {p_1, p, p_2, p, ...} is convergent then lim p_n = p.

Comment: Well your statement is "A sequence of point ${p_1,p,p_2,p,...}$ is convergent if and only if $\lim\limits_{n \to \infty}p_n=p$ which mean you have to show both ways

Comment: Oh, that is simple. My math tutor had problems with my 1 way. So i was confused, cuz i think its essentially the same proof but reverse, nothing to add.